# Converting Curl command to Powershell invoke rest-method

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

Does anyone know how to convert this Curl command to PowerShell invoke rest-method. Using PowerShell version 5.1.

```
curl -vqgsSkH "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --no-progress-bar --header "X-FeApi-Token: "Tokenn string"=" -F "filename=@C:\Users\User\Documents\all.csv" -F "options={\"application\":\"2\",\"timeout\":\"500\",\"priority\":\"0\", \"profiles\":[\"win7-sp1\"],\"analysistype\":\"1\",\"force\":\"true\", \"prefetch\":\"0\"}" https://<URL>:443/wsapis/v2.0.0/submissions/file
```

Comment: since win10 includes the  windows version of `curl.exe` ... i would just use that in your PoSh script.